# Cross-thread operations WinForms app

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms

Is there a simple, practically reusable way/method to do long-running cross-thread operations? What I mean is, I need to to some stuff that will take a while (Sending mail, uploading to DB and FTP server) but I also need to interact with the Form and its controls at the same time.

Comment: So... what's the problem? You can put long-running operations on a different thread and if you need to access a control simply delegate the call to the UI thread.

Comment: [Parallel Processing and Concurrency in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156548(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thank you PoweredByOrange, and thank you @JimMischel, I am looking at that link now. I have to admit, the terminology would have to be the hardest part about learning for me. It's probably the reason why 90% of my searches never yield helpful results. For some reason, I can remember other things, but the terminology just doesn't seem to stick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many options.  The main issue is that you need to push the work into a separate thread, but not access your controls from that thread.

The most common mechanisms to do this would be to use:

- [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker)
- Using [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) / [`Task<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- Creating threads manually

Comment: @JimMischel That doesn't handle threading issues directly, though you can use it to make writing your code simpler when using Task/Task<T>.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `BackgroundWorker` class. This will allow to to run long running processes, while updating the UI, without having to manually `Invoke()` UI updates to the UI Thread, which you would have to do if manually using Threads.

Answer (score 0):

You want the Invoke/BeginInvoke method of your form to allow corssthread operations with the UI.

The best is to create a class which performs the long task in another thread and has some events to signal the form, then in the form you can use this.BeginInvoke to execute the UI operations in the main thread.